# Creating a login component behind app component

Tags: angular, routes

I've got an angular website with several routes for different components.

I defined on the app.component.html that the routing area it's about 70% of the screen, with some menus and logos on the other 30% - static- - and those menus and logos are shown in every screen/component.

The problem now is: I want to create a login screen, "behind" the main app (without the menus, logos, etc). If I route to it, the menus won't disappear - not surprising.

I've got this routes on `app.module.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'inicio', component: InicioComponent },
  { path: 'list-my-aval', component: ListMyAvalComponent},
  { path: 'create-my-aval', component: CreateMyAvalComponent},
  { path: 'new-calendario', component: NewCalendarioComponent},
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'},

];
```

What do u suggest me to do in order to solve this problem?
Ps: im a begginer

Comment: Please share your routing.module file

Comment: updated, I've got this var

Comment: You can implement guards and conditionally hide the navbar, check a [**tutorial here**](https://loiane.com/2017/08/angular-hide-navbar-login-page/) and a working [stackblitz demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-login-hide-navbar-ngif-demo?file=src/app/home/home.component.ts), hope this is helpful !

Comment: you can add app.component.html to your question

Answer (score 0):

If your okay with putting all logged in components in a deeper route like: `/secure/inicio` and `/secure/list-my-aval`, and putting the login component top route like: `/login`, than you can simply use a child router, like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'secure',
        component: SecureComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'inicio', component: InicioComponent },
            { path: 'list-my-aval', component: ListMyAvalComponent },
            { path: 'create-my-aval', component: CreateMyAvalComponent },
            { path: 'new-calendario', component: NewCalendarioComponent },
        ]
    },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
];
```